# Select all data include another table even if null

Tags: mysql, sql

Setup:
(1) Employee table (employeeID, firstName, lastName)

(1) Shoe table (shoeID, Employee_employeeID, shoeName, shoeColor, shoeBrand)

I want to select all rows in Employee table and even if there is no matching EmployeeID (Employee_EmployeeID) in the shoe table display that entire row anyway. Example desired output:

```
 EmployeeID  | firstName    | lastName    | shoeName     |   shoeColor  | shoeBrand

 1            John           Smith         AirMax2          Red          Nike
 2            Ronald         Mcdonald      null             null         null
 3            James          Knight        null             null         null
 4            Cindy          Smith         Pump             Brown        Cole Haan
```

I have tried a lot of different joins and I will get duplicate rows for each Employee.

Comment: I thought this is exactly what a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` does… am I missing something? Is there, like, more than one shoe per employee, but you want the database engine to arbitrarily choose one shoe to return?

Comment: What Matchu said. Also, show some of the queries you tried so we can tell you what you're doing wrong :)

Comment: Yes, you're both right. I thought I had read and understood the left join.. apparently not. Thank for the replies.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT e.employeeId,e.firstName,e.lastName,s.ShoeName,s.ShoeColor,s.ShoeBrand 
   FROM    Employee e
   LEFT JOIN Shoe s
   ON e.employeeID = s.Employee_employeeID
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=2/a82f7/2#!2/8dd1f/2)

Comment: This is correct.. Marking it as the answer because it was up voted. Thanks!

Comment: nice that it helped you , you welcome ! good luck with the rest!

Comment: How do I do this if I have a `WHERE x=?`?

Comment: @Marcel pretty old and you probably figured it out, just want to add it for completeness sake anyway. You can append for example `WHERE e.lastName="radi"` at the end of echo_Me's query, tested in his SQLFiddle.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out with my homework.

Answer (score 10):

You need a `left outer join`:

```
select e.employeeid, e.firstname, e.lastname, s.shorname, s.shoecolor, s.shoebrand
from employee e left outer join
     shoe s
     on e.employeeid = s.employeeid
```

Answer (score 7):

You are going to want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select e.employeeId,
  e.firstName,
  e.lastName,
  s.ShoeName,
  s.ShoeColor,
  s.ShoeBrand
from Employee e
left join shoe s
  on e.employeeID = s.Employee_employeeID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1a76/1)

A `LEFT JOIN` will return the matching rows from the `employee` table even if there is not a matching row in the `shoe` table.

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Now, if you wanted all rows that match both tables, then you would use an `INNER JOIN`.