# SQL join 2 tables with condition taking some default NULL values due to condition

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement, join, inner-join

I am taking some data from tables using join,

```
    SELECT da.aName AS aName FROM dbo.bTable 
INNER JOIN aTable da ON dbo.bTable.nameType = da.ID"
```

This select works. But if nameType is some new number which is not in da.ID, then this row is not shown at all. what I want is to join these to tables, but if aTable does not contain such number at all then some default values must be taken.

Here is an example.
aTable is table of names

```
id=1 aName = bmw
id=2 aName= mersedes
id=3 aName= audi
```

bTable has list of cars and I must get them all

```
1    nameType =1
2    nameType =2
3    nameType =3
4    nameType =5
```

So I must show all 4 cars.
And with my code I will show only 3, because nameType of number 4 car is 5. And there is no such ID in aTable.
The result will be

> 1 car is bmw
>
> 2 car is mersedes
>
> 3 car is audi

What I want to do is in such case aTable to give some NULL values or something so the result must be like

> 1 car is bmw
>
> 2 car is mersedes
>
> 3 car is audi
>
> 4 car is NULL

Comment: Mercedes, with a _c_...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all data include another table even if null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740438/select-all-data-include-another-table-even-if-null)

Comment: This is a RIGHT JOIN n which is n LEFT JOIN a. LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Similarly for RIGHT JOIN. FULL JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. These are the OUTER JOINs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Which like most faqs will be found by doing what should be done before considering posting re any question/problem/goal--google many clear concise precise phrasings of it with & without specific strings. I just cut & pasted & genericized to "join but if the right table does not contain such value at all then null site:stackoverflow.com" & the 1st faq was the duplicate link, although it was a faq too when asked. Duplicates if asked should be linked & not answered.

Comment: @philipxy, Sorry, I can be hard to read. I mean this "quality level/research" is  "normal". lately all his question look like Dupe/Typo/Basics. It must be a tutorial or something as I can't imagine how you can produce any code without an understanding of Or/And for exemple.

Comment: [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645844/force-join-to-join-all-data-even-if-parameter-is-null-left-join) two weeks ago?

Comment: @DragandDrop Oh dear. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

```
SELECT da.aName AS aName 
FROM dbo.bTable 
LEFT JOIN aTable da ON dbo.bTable.nameType = da.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need `Outer Join` and Don't use `Inner Join`

because inner join *selects records that have matching values in both tables*

```
SELECT da.aName AS aName 
FROM dbo.bTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN aTable da ON dbo.bTable.nameType = da.ID"
```